# get_query_var('post_type') not returning in a filter

Tags: menus, navigation

Trying to highlight custom taxonomy pages in the main nav, so I am trying to get the `post_type` of the current rendered page (to compare to the menu item):

```
add_filter('nav_menu_css_class', 'current_tax_nav_class', 10, 2);
function current_tax_nav_class($classes, $item) {
    $post_type = get_query_var('post_type');

    echo ">>>";
    print_r( $post_type );
    echo "<<<";

    return $classes;
}
```

But cannot get post_type var to return anything. This code is in functions.php

Using WP Version 4.4.1

Comment: Are you trying to get the post_type of the element you are about to render in a menu?

Comment: I'm trying to get the post_type of the current displayed page

Comment: Does the answer below help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to get the post type for the current 'post', I think you could go with `get_post_type()`.

Like this:

```
$post_type = get_post_type();
```

Try it out.

Comment: I think it would be better: `get_post_type( get_queried_object() );` Other than that, `get_post_type()` function works in the filter, I've tested it.

Comment: So that works... sort of... It works on pages, but when I'm on an archive page of a taxonomy it only returns if the taxonomy has posts associated with it, which means that if taxonomy has nothing, the post_type returns empty...

Comment: Well, that would be correct, right? A taxonomy doesn't necessary have a post_type associated. What post type would you want returned on an empty taxonomy?